# What propulsion method: Franky Zapata hoverboard

Tags: aerospace-engineering

Looking for the answer to what kind of engine provides the thrust on the French hoverboard on which its inventor, Franky Zapata, recently crossed the English Channel, I find the same phrase repeated everywhere: it's a "turbine engine". Exactly what is it? A turbojet? A turbofan? A turboprop? It is fuelled by paraffin (kerosene). Is all the thrust produced by propellers in a ducted fan configuration or does exhaust gas contribute?